# Free Transform ID with Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, raphael, transform

I have little knowledge on Raphael JS and I need help. 
Want to apply a free transform an image, but rather to inform the image link in js, I need the code apply freetransform through the ID of the image.

I'm using this:

```
var img = r.image('http://www.porcopedia.com/images/thumb/Simbolo_Goi%C3%A1s.jpg/600px-Simbolo_Goi%C3%A1s.jpg', 10, 10, 200, 200);
```

'd Like something like this:

```
var img = r.image('myID', 10, 10, 200, 200);
```

Please help me. Grateful!

Here is what I did so far. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/murilobu/LJTPU/5/)